# Drain skill in order to get cheaper level trains?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you drain a skill in order to get cheaper level trains in Skyrim?

If so, where can I create a drain skill spell?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about training costs considering you can pickpocket back the money afterwards ;)

Comment: There are diseases that lower certain skills, but I can't confirm that this lowers the training prices. And as I am now immune to disease, I can't easily check for you. Can anyone test this?

Answer (score 3):

There isnt a drain skill spell, it's as simple as that. They got rid of this for the exact reason you are asking.

Comment: i should add... if you really want to do this to level up quickly... you can use the console command "player.SetAV <skillname> <##>". enter the console with the '~' key and enter that code without the <>s.